# AgGrid master/detail detail grid rows to have different height

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on a master/detail table in AgGrid. The functionality is nothing special besides that I want the detail grid to have a smaller height than the main grid. See image.

[image]

I was trying everything, and it seems that there is no way to set the rowHeight on the detail separately then on the main grid. There is a setting for the height of the row that expands `detailRowHeight` but this sets the height of the containing row not the rows of the sub grid.

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `rowHeight` on the detail grid is the same as you would do for a normal grid, simply add the grid property `rowHeight` or the grid callback `getRowHeight` (for dynamic row heights) to the `detailGridOptions`:

```
    this.detailCellRendererParams = {
      detailGridOptions: {
        getRowHeight: (params) => 30,
        // [...]
      },
      getDetailRowData: function (params) {
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
      },
    };
```

See this implemented in the following sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/AyJ0xvM0EHC6Pce1

Comment: My problem was that I also had an override in the CSS to specify line-height and even I set the height in the JS I still need to change the CSS. Putting it here if anyone bumps into the same issue.
@shuheb thanks!

Comment: @Shuheb In same example, can you set master row height to 22px? if yes can you tell me how?